# Strange error while trying to deploy qt5 app on raspberry pi

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi, qt5, raspbian

I have a project which I've made on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, but then, I wanted to test if the Raspberry Pi was capable of running this little program of mine.
Then I've followed the instructions on this [link](https://wiki.qt.io/Native_Build_of_Qt5_on_a_Raspberry_Pi) to compile and build qt5 natively on the Pi.

I've managed to install qt5 without problems, I could even compile and run the "cube" program that is located on the qt samples.

After that, I've compiled and installed the qtmultimedia submodule, which I needed for my project.

Ok, things were looking good. Then I cloned my project on the Pi, ran qmake, and after that I ran make. Until... I got this error message:

```
In file included from ../mainWindow.h:14:0,
             from ../main.cpp:3:
../core/core.h: In constructor ‘bumbatv::core::Core::Core()’:
../core/core.h:37:36: error: conversion from ‘int’ to ‘QString’ is ambiguous
../core/core.h:37:36: note: candidates are:
/usr/local/qt5/include/QtCore/qstring.h:649:31: note: QString::QString(const char*)
/usr/local/qt5/include/QtCore/qstring.h:214:14: note: QString::QString(const QChar*, int)
Makefile:2564: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Thing is... In this particular area of the code, I have no conversion from int to QString!

```
class Core : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
private:
    static Core *instance_;
    QHash <int, Channel*> channels_;
    int currentChannelId_;
    QString computerName_;
    QString projectDirectory_; 
    Definitions::kPlayerStatus player_;
    QHash<int, Media*> medias_;
    QString userEmail_;
    QString userPassword_;
    QString userPasswordEncrypted_;
    bool logged_;

    Core(){
        Channel *channel = new Channel; // This is the error line.
        channels_.insert(channel->getId(),channel);
        currentChannelId_ = channel->getId();
        player_ = Definitions::kStopped;
        logged_ = false;
    }

    Core(const Core&);
    Core& operator=(const Core&);
    /* Protect destructor.
     * Deletes all elements allocated in the Document.
     */
    ~Core()
    {
        // Delete channels
        foreach (Channel *c, channels_)
            delete c;
    }
(...)
}
```

And here's the Channel constructor:

```
        class Channel : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
private:

    static int countChannel_; 
    int idChannel_; 
    QString label_; 
    int currentMediaId_; 
    int totalTime_; 
    int order_; 

    QHash<int, Media*> medias_;  


signals:
    (...)

public:
    Channel(int id = -1, int order = -1, int totalTime = -1, QString label = NULL) {
        if(id==-1){
            idChannel_ = countChannel_++;
        }else{
            idChannel_ = id;
            countChannel_ = countChannel_ <= id ? id+1 : countChannel_;
        }

        order_ = order == -1 ? idChannel_ : order;
        totalTime_ = totalTime == -1 ? 0 : totalTime;
        label_ = label == NULL ? QString("Channel %1").arg(idChannel_+1) : label;
    }

    /* Protect destructor.
     * Deletes all elements allocated in the Channel.
     */
    ~Channel()
    {
        // Delete medias
        foreach (Media *m, medias_)
            delete m;
    }
(...)

}
```

And here is the command called by make:

```
/usr/bin/g++ -c -pipe -marm -mfpu=vfp -mtune=arm1176jzf-s -march=armv6zk -mabi=aapcs-linux -mfloat-abi=hard -O2 -std=c++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_NO_SSL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_MULTIMEDIAWIDGETS_LIB -DQT_MULTIMEDIA_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../../vodas_desktop -I. -I/usr/local/qt5/include -I/usr/local/qt5/include/QtMultimediaWidgets -I/usr/local/qt5/include/QtMultimedia -I/usr/local/qt5/include/QtWidgets -I/usr/local/qt5/include/QtGui -I/usr/local/qt5/include/QtNetwork -I/usr/local/qt5/include/QtXml -I/usr/local/qt5/include/QtCore -I. -I/opt/vc/include -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vmcs_host/linux -I/usr/local/qt5/mkspecs/devices/linux-rasp-pi-g++ -o main.o ../main.cpp
```

So... Any thoughts? I have no idea of what is wrong. My code compiles on ubuntu and on Windows without this error message.

Comment: We need to see all of your Core class and constructor

Comment: There it is. Plus, the channel constructor. @dwcanillas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your default argument for `QString` isn't valid:

```
QString label = NULL
```

`NULL` is just a macro for 0, so you are effectively saying `QString label = 0`.  `QString` doesn't define a way to create a `QString` from an `int`, which is the reason for your error - on most platforms I'm guessing the `QString(const char *)` constructor would get called with an implicit conversion from `0` to `const char *`.

It looks like your pi had trouble figuring out how to implicitly convert that `0`.  Change it to `QString label = ""`, `QString label = QString()`, or something similar.

Comment: I'll try to do that. Will be back in a bit.

Comment: It seems to be working! But the raspberry is a little slow to compile, so I'll let you know if everything went ok. Thanks!